# "Goto Source" opens pgflibraryfadings.code.tex

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texlive, editors, forward-inverse-search

**Edit:** Seems to be a problem with SyncTeX, as TeXworks reacts the same.
**Edit2:** same problem with `texlive` in Win7.

I have a similiar problem as described in [TeXstudio Bugreport 1225](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1225/) 
but with `menukeys`-package.

consider the following MWE for reconstructing the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{menukeys}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\keys{CTRL + X} in \directory{File/Save As}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

It compiles fine, but when I click on "Goto Source" in the embedded viewer, `pgflibraryfadings.code.tex` is opened instead. This only happens on the first page of any document. Any clues on a fix?

Setup:
I use MiKTeX 2.9 (64bit), TeXstudio 2.10.8 on a Win7 machine.

Secondary setup: 
TeX Live 2015, TeXworks, Win7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After debugging that problem for a while (It bothers me, too, currently), I've came up with a work-around. But please use with care: I found the source of the problem, but I don't really know what I'm doing here ;-)

After debugging for a while, I found out that `libraries/pgflibraryfadings.code.tex` (note, all paths are relative to `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/`) is included from 
`frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryfadings.code.tex` and uses the macro `\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading`, which is defined in `basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex`. This uses `\pgfsys@horishading` which is defined in `systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def` and contains somewhere the line `\immediate\pdfxform resources ...` in the definition of `\pgfsys@horishading`, and this is the main culprit. The problem seems to be the `\immediate` which ships out something immediately to the PDF and seems to confuse `pdflatex`. If you remove the `\immediate` everything seems to work fine. So I would propose the following workflow:

1. Copy `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def` to your current tex working directory.
2. Locate the lines containing `\immediate\pdfxform` after 
   `\def\pgfsys@horishading#1#2#3{%`,
   `\def\pgfsys@vertshading#1#2#3{%`, and
   `\def\pgfsys@radialshading#1#2#3{%` and remove the `\immediate`.
3. The shading stuff still works for me, but maybe before the final build, you want to remove the file `pgfsys-pdftex.def` from your working directory again, to be sure the original version is used.

Comment: thanks for the effort, but please don't be upset when I don't mark this as "accepted". I'd like to have the problem solved on a more permanent level and of course without the hacking around. I've tested your method and it does work, but it's too much of a hassle to do this everytime. I'd appreciate if you could send your findings to the DEV team of the respective package. much obliged

Comment: I posted it here: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/333/. However, I think its best to have both: a quick fix to continue working, *and* to have it fixed upstream.

Comment: Did not help me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem when using the tikzlibrary "shadows".

As proposed [here](https://www.franziskuskiefer.de/post/pgflibraryfadings/), if the library is not being used, **removing it** "solves" the problem.

```
%\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
```

Comment: There isn't much to add to my post. The problem is described above by naphaneal and the solution, as stated in the 2nd sentence of my post, is to remove the library if not used. Nevertheless, I made some modifications to my post.

Comment: To be precise, [the problem is with tikzlibrary "fadings"](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/SyncTeX_Errors), which "shadows" internally uses. You may also encounter the same issue with other things that use "fadings", such as the `todonotes` package.

Comment: I needed to remove both tiks and pgf package usages from the preamble for this to work. Thanks!

Comment: Another source of this problem is the `most` option for package `tcolorbox`.

Comment: Switching back from lualatex to xelatex solved the problem for me.