# SyncTeX jumps to pgflibraryfadings in TeXstudio with todonotes

Tags: luatex, texstudio, forward-inverse-search, todonotes

If I <kbd>ctrl + mouse click</kbd> on the output text in TeXstudio with the code below then it takes me to `pgflibraryfadings.code.tex` which is not what I would expect/like.  What can I do to fix this?  (LuaTeX engine)

*EDIT*
The problem appears to be related to how LuaTeX generates the SyncTeX files.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks like a TeXstudio issue and should probably be reported to [TeXstudio bug tracking on Github](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues).

Comment: see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/300079/100482 for possible answer

Comment: Thanks @naphaneal That doesn't do it though.   I went so far as to replace all \immediate commands, but nope.

Comment: Incidentally, it appears to be a synctex problem more than a texstudio problem.